# How to add more reasons in the dropdown for cancels the order in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

When I try to cancel the order it has only 4 options

The customer changed/ cancelled order, fraudulent Order, item unavailable, others

I want to add 1 more option i.e. "COD Service Not Available".

How to add this option in the dropdown while canceling orders

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you cant add options to the cancel reason dropdown. The Shopify documentation for [Order's `cancel_reason` property](http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#cancel-reason-property) states:

> ```
> { "cancel_reason" : "null" }
> ```
>
> The reason why the order was cancelled. If the order was not cancelled, this value is "null." If the order was cancelled, the value will be one of the following:
>
> - **customer**: The customer changed or cancelled the order.
> - **fraud**: The order was fraudulent.
> - **inventory**: Items in the order were not in inventory.
> - **other**: The order was cancelled for a reason not in the list above.

The best option would probably be to select "Other" and add a note or tag to the order.

Comment: Even if you created your own app to cancel orders, the `cancel_reason` for an Order can still only be one of the [4 options specified in the documentation](http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#cancel).